# PHP Constructor Calling itself - Not Recurrsion

Tags: php, namespaces

I am adding some modules to a PHP framework that is already in place and working flawlessly.  It supports multiple database drivers.  I am looking at the main system logic.

I noticed that in one of the main database driver class constructors, it calls/instantiates itself.  I am not going to alter this code but I am confused as to why this doesn't result in an endless recursive loop.

I have looked into new PHP namespace and constructor documentation and it doesn't pacify any of my confusion.

The main MySQLi driver code for the framework looks like this:

```php
<?php

namespace SimFr\System\Library\DB;


class MySQLi {
    private $connection;

    public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port = '3306') {
        $mysqli = @new \MySQLi($hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port);

        if (!$mysqli->connect_error) {
            $this->connection = $mysqli;
            $this->connection->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR;

        } else {
            throw new \Exception('MySQLi DB Failure');
        }
    }

... rest of class logic ...
```

I am wondering how in the constructor, when it assigns to a variable (`$mysqli`) an object of itself, it doesn't get stuck in a recursive loop.

Is my understanding of namespaces inaccurate?  Thanks for your help in understanding.

Comment: Yes, it's your understanding of namespaces which is inaccurate. Notice the *backslash* in front of \MySQLi. So it's a completely different class

Comment: Okay, i will do more research on namespaces.  However, there is no root namespace class for MySQLi - so I assumed it created the class based on the current class in the root namespace.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: What does it mean, "there is no root namespace class for MySQLi"?Original MySQLi class *is* in the root namespace just like all other PHP's builtin classes. \ in fromt of the class name explicitly means "the root namespace"

Comment: i feel pretty stupid. i have no idea why that didnt register.  thanks

Comment: What is this line `$this->connection->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR;`? It makes no sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my understanding of namespaces inaccurate?

Yes, but this is a bity tricky because of the naming. This:

```
namespace SimFr\System\Library\DB;
class MySQLi { ... }
```

Makes a class called `\SimFr\System\Library\DB\MySQLi`, while this:

```
$mysqli = @new \MySQLi(...)
```

Refers to a class called `\MySQLi`.

The first class reference (the definition) has no leading blackslash, so it is put into whatever the current namespace is. The second class reference (the instantiation) has a leading backslash, which explicitly puts it in the root namespace. So, you have two classes with the same name, but they're in different namespaces, and are thus different classes.

Comment: How does this prevent the recursive loop then?  It creates the class, with same logic im assuming?  So how does the constructor not call itself in same root namespace again?

Comment: There is no recursive loop. The `\SimFr\System\Library\DB\MySQLi` constructor creates an instance of `\MySQLi`, which is a different class with its own constructor.

Comment: Okay, i guess im having trouble finding the root namespaced MySQLi class.  It doesnt seem to exist....

Comment: It's a PHP built-in, like `\DateTime`.

Comment: Heh don't sweat it, namespacing can be tricky. I think in this case, one would normally extend `\MySQLi` instead of creating a same-named wrapper around it, and so it's a little odd to understand why this was done.

Comment: Yeah there are some upgrades needed for sure

Comment: Actually "composition over inheritance" is frequently advocated as a *better* way to design things. In this case, extending the built-in class would mean all its methods were available by default, but not integrated with any of the features added by the wrapper, which could get very confusing. Using the name MySQLi for the wrapper is perhaps not the best choice though; maybe they should have called it MySQLj or something 

Comment: interesting... definitely will consider when refactoring.  Ill call it OurSQLi.  JK, but thanks for the help guys